# Eclipse: Nested Editor Tabs?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is anyone aware of any method (or external plugin) that would allow for nested editor tabs? It would be nice to be able to group related open files into their own "master" tabs, but I'm not sure if this is even possible. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is totally non-obvious, and I discovered it by accident, but...

If you click on a tab and start dragging it downwards, once you get more than half-way down the editor pane, a horizontal line will appear.  Let go, and now you'll have two different editor panes, each with tabs of documents.  Now you can drag tabs up and down between the two panes to see different documents at the same time.

I think that's as close as you can get.

Comment: I've noticed this as well. Certainly not ideal, but it may be the best option at the  moment.

Comment: You can also drag the tab outside the main Eclipse window (e.g., on to another monitor) and get a floating editor window.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best you can currently do is "Window->New Window" and then use each new window as a separate "tab" of related editors. Not exactly ideal, I admit.

It's a cool idea though, especially if you could have shortcuts or something that open groups of editors with a single command.

Answer (score 2):

This definitely isn't possible in the current RCP.  You might be able to construct an editor component which created a `CTabFolder` and delegated to other editor components, but I'm not sure how well that would work.

Answer (score 1):

There are *Perspectives* in Eclipse that you might use to achieve something close, they are more global things though...

But I agree with you, I would like this feature as well! This would be also very useful when editing many files that have the same name but come from different packages, because now it's a mess >_<

Answer (score 0):

For me the utility of such a feature is to reduce context switching time. I'm working on project A, have lots of editors open, now I need to drop that and work on project B. I want to keep all the editors open associated with project A but hide them while I work on B. When I'm done with B, I can pick up right where I left off in A without having to find and open all those A files again; I can even leave them unsaved indefinitely, since Juno never crashes!! :)

I have used the New Window feature, and it's great, but the new window needs a bunch of configuration (closing Views I don't need, moving stuff around to where I want it, opening Views I had open in the old window, and so on) before I can get to work. It also uses a lot more memory than a simple tab group would since it seems to be a complete new copy of Eclipse.

The split-window feature is great and I use it all the time. It is indeed tab groups, and if there were a way to hide a tab group, and for each tab group to have its own tab list (the thing you get when you click ">>5" so you can see editors you have open that don't fit in the tab header), it would totally fill the bill.